# Can anybody show me how to properly install sklearn.preprocessing for spyder app?

Tags: python, ipython, lstm, spyder

I am new to python. I wanted to build an LSTM model for weekly covid-19 cases and I am stuck with  (from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler), can anybody show me how to install it properly>

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8tBD.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html)?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) You need to follow [these instructions](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/5/faq.html#using-packages-installer).